# Finding eigenvectors and eigenvalues of a sparse matrix with ARPACK ( called form PYTHON, MATLAB or as a FORTRAN subroutine)

Tags: sparse-matrix, eigenvector, eigenvalue, arpack

Few days ago I asked a question how to find the eigenvalues of a large sparse matrix. I got no answers, so I decided to describe a potential solution.

```
One question remains: 
Can I use the python implementation of ARPACK 
to compute the eigenvalues of a asymmetric sparse matrix.
```

At the beginning I would like to say that it is not at all necessary to call the subroutines of ARPACK directly using FOTRAN driver program. That is quite difficult and I never got it going. But one can do the following:

#

OPTION 1: Python

#

One can install numpy and scipy and run the following code:

```
import numpy as np
from scipy.linalg import eigh
from scipy.sparse.linalg import eigsh
from scipy.sparse import *
from scipy import * 

# coordinate format storage of the matrix

# rows
ii = array([0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 4])
# cols.
jj = array([0, 1, 0, 1, 2, 1, 2, 3, 2, 3, 4])
# and the data
data=array([1.,-1.,-1., 2.,-2.,-2., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1.])
# now put this into sparse storage (CSR-format)
m=csr_matrix( (data,(ii,jj)), shape=(5,5) )
# you can check what you did 
matrix([[ 1, -1,  0,  0,  0],
        [-1,  2, -2,  0,  0],
        [ 0, -2,  1,  1,  0],
        [ 0,  0,  1,  1,  0],
        [ 0,  0,  0,  0,  1]])

# the real part starts here
evals_large, evecs_large = eigsh(m, 4, which='LM')
# print the largest 4 eigenvalues
print evals_all
# and the values are
[-1.04948118  1.          1.48792836  3.90570354]
```

Well this is all very nice, specially because it spears us the joy of reading the very "well written" manual of ARPACK.

I have a problem with this, I think that it doesn't work with asymmetric matrices. At least comparing the results to matlab was not very convincing.

#

OPTION 2: MATLAB

#

```
       % put your data in a file "matrix.dat"
       % row col. data
       % note that indexing starts at "1"
       1 1 1.
       1 2 -1.
       ......

       load matrix.dat
       M = spconvert(matrix)

       [v,d] = eig(M)

       % v - contains the eigenvectors
       % d - contains the eigenvalues
```

I think that using matlab is way simpler and works for asymmetric matrices. Well I have a 500000x500000 sparse matrix, so whether this will work in matlab .... Is another cup of tea! I have to note that using python I was able to load matrix of this size and compute it's eigenvalues without too much of a trouble.

Cheers,

Comment: is there any option for Fortran only? Avoiding the ARPACK "manual-nightmare" I mean

Comment: It was long time ago since i did this. Basically for symmetric matrices you could use the python implementation and for general cases the Matlab one. ARPACK is Fortran. To run it you need to write your own vector matrix multiplication function and call it in conjunction with ARPACK. Unfortunately, I always had some doubts about my implementation and just used matlab. In general, the manual is quite hard to follow. In my question I have included some examples how to run from python and matlab.